# how to check java console logs after it is closed

Tags: safari, applet, java-web-start

I have a java applet to be run in browser, when it is started by jre plugin its console starts but before i could see something, it gets closed. Is there a way to chcek these console logs even if it is closed? may be some file or something where it is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Tracing in Java Control Panel. This way the console outputs are saved in a file here:

```
<User Application Data Folder>\Sun\Java\Deployment\log
```

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp/tracing_logging.html